# DatePickerDialog in Android

Tags: java, android

There is problem when the dialog opens, and pressing ok again nothing happens, but when you press edittext again, everything works properly. I think there is one dialogue calendar surplus. Does anyone maybe know? Thank you

```
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    
    
            //final Calendar mCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    
            final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePocetnoVreme = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                                      int dayOfMonth) {
                    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                    if (brojacZavrsnoVreme == 0) {
                        brojacZavrsnoVreme = 1;
                    } else {
                        showTimePicker(true);
                        brojacZavrsnoVreme = 0;
                    }
    
                }
    
            };
            pocetnoVremeEditText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    new DatePickerDialog(Unos.this,R.style.DialogTheme,datePocetnoVreme,calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
                }
            });
    
    
            final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateZavrsnoVreme = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                                      int dayOfMonth) {
                    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                    if (brojacZavrsnoVreme == 0) {
                        brojacZavrsnoVreme = 1;
                    } else {
                        showTimePicker(false);
                        brojacZavrsnoVreme = 0;
                    }
    
                }
    
            };
    
            zavrsnoVremeEditText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    new DatePickerDialog(Unos.this, dateZavrsnoVreme, calendar
                            .get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                            calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
                }
            });
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Want to Show DatePicker, Set Date The Press Ok to show TimePicker and Set Time
I Use This Code In My Project And it Work Perfectly to this use case

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy h:mm a", Locale.getDefault());
private void pickDateTime(){
        final Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        final Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                date.set(year, month, dayOfMonth);
                new TimePickerDialog(getContext(), new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                        date.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                        date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                       
                        String selectedDateTime = simpleDateFormat.format(date.getTime());
                    }
                },currentDate.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), currentDate.get(Calendar.MINUTE), false).show();
            }
        }, currentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR), currentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH), currentDate.get(Calendar.DATE));
        datePickerDialog.show();
    }
```

Example Of Output: 23-Feb-2021 10:51

**Preview**
[image: example of working code]

Comment: Can you give me your email please?

Comment: How Can I Sent it private ?

Comment: write it here, i will delete it

Comment: Okay, I delete it. I will mesage you.

Answer (score 1):

Where is this variable defined ? brojacZavrsnoVreme
I think its has initial value of zero , so when you set the your date , your if condition if ==0 is satisfied and set its value to 1 and stop without showing you the selected date , the second time the condition if ==1 satisfied and show you the selected date .

Comment: I can't tell unless in know what is used for and where its declared , can you show me the whole code , i think you have to use a meaningful names so that any one can understand what is it for .

Answer (score 0):

Why did you write 2 DatePickerDialog? Anyway, you can create it this way:

1. Create DatePicker() method

```
    private void DatePicker(){

        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener (){

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                mCalendar.set ( Calendar.YEAR, year );
                mCalendar.set ( Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                mCalendar.set ( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth );
                updateLabel();
            }
        };

        yourEditText.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new DatePickerDialog ( getContext (),date,mCalendar
                        .get ( Calendar.YEAR ), mCalendar.get ( Calendar.MONTH ), mCalendar.get ( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH ) ).show ();
            }
        } );
    }
```

2. Formatting text from the date picked

```
    private void updateLabel() {
        String mFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat (mFormat, Locale.US);
        editBuyDate.setText ( sdf.format ( mCalendar.getTime() ) );

    }
```

3. Call the DatePicker() method inside onCreate:

```
DatePicker();
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need this piece of code and all is done then.
Pass OnDateSetListener and use selected date there.

```
public static void setupDatePickerDialogue(Context context, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener onDateSetListener)
    {
        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(context,onDateSetListener
                ,Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)
                ,Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH)
                ,Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
        datePickerDialog.setCancelable(false);
        datePickerDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        datePickerDialog.show();
    }
```